# Upload picture in Access Form, but store the picture outside the database

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

Im am new to this database design. I've read a lot that storing pictures inside a database is pointless, therefore im looking for a VBA code that allows me to "upload" pictures in an access form, but store the actual file outside the DB while writting a Hyperlink to the picture in the Recordset.

I cant find anything like this online.

Comment: "I've read a lot..." Stop right there! So you've read this a lot, but do you have any idea why that advice is common? What's the reasoning behind it? Does that reasoning really apply to your case? Even having some kind of "image save" function combined with an Access database and a VBA form is already getting into uncommon territory, so it might not make any sense for you! What are you going to do with the image?

Comment: There are pro's and con's with either saving internally as an attachment or saving externally and keeping a link. I disagree that it is 'pointless', but at the end of the day, it's your call regarding which way you go. To make the external method work you need: (1) a table which has fields for the full path plus some description; (2) A UI form to find/save an image and create / update the path in the table; (3) maybe a UI that will display images you have saved. Advice: don't start moving your application/images to a different folder!

Answer (score 1):

It is all very easy in MS Access 2010, just bind an image control to a table of paths. For example, my table is called Pictures, with the following entries.

```
PicturePath
Z:\Users\Fionnuala\Pictures\abc.png
Z:\Users\Fionnuala\Pictures\abc.jpg
```

I now just need an image control on a form bound to the table Pictures with a control source set to PicturePath, the images will be displayed.

You can also break down the path to the subfolder and name, for example, \Pictures\abc.png, so that with a little work in VBA, you can create a full path based on the subfolder.

If you prefer, you can use an Attachment data type and upload images.

Comment: Ok, im going to give it a try! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I found what i wanted to do.

This gets the attachmet outside the database, in a spcecific folder, and then it stores the path in a table field.

```
Public Function SaveAttachments(strPath As String, ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal Table_Field_Picture_FILE As String, Optional strPattern As String = "*.*") As Long 'ByVal strSQL As String, ByVal Campo As String,
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsA As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim rsB As DAO.Recordset2
    Dim fld As DAO.Field2
    Dim strFullPath As String
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim prm As DAO.Parameter

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    'strSQL = "SELECT * FROM SubFSolDesc WHERE NumeroSolicitud= " & Screen.ActiveForm.SolicitudID & ";"

    'Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset("SubFSolDesc")
    Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)
    Set fld = rst([Table_Field_Picture_FILE]) '"FotografiaProyecto") '

    'Navigate through the table
    Do While Not rst.EOF

        'Get the recordset for the Attachments field
        Set rsA = fld.value

        'Save all attachments in the field
        Do While Not rsA.EOF

            If rsA("FileName") Like strPattern Then
                strFullPath = strPath & "\" & rsA("FileName")
                Debug.Print strFullPath

                'Make sure the file does not exist and save
                If Dir(strFullPath) = "" Then
                    rsA("FileData").SaveToFile strFullPath

                End If

                'Increment the number of files saved
                SaveAttachments = SaveAttachments + 1

            End If

            'Next attachment
            rsA.Delete
            rsA.MoveNext
        Loop
        rsA.Close

                        With rst
                        .Edit
                        ![Desired_Path_Field] = strFullPath
                        .Update
                        End With
        'Next record
        rst.MoveNext
    Loop

    rst.Close
    dbs.Close

    Set fld = Nothing
    Set rsA = Nothing
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
End Function
```